# How to set TCP_NODELAY flag when loading URL with urllib2?

Tags: python, sockets, urllib2, urlopen, setsockopt

I am using urllib2 for loading web-page, my code is:

```
httpRequest = urllib2.Request("http:/www....com")
pageContent = urllib2.urlopen(httpRequest)
pageContent.readline()
```

How can I get hold of the socket properties to set `TCP_NODELAY`?

In normal socket I would be using function:

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

Comment: Why do you set it when calling a web server???

Comment: I am polling a website at specific time, when some information should be published there. The speed is very important, so setting TCP_NODELAY avoid accumulating small portions of data into bigger portionos before sending packet.

Comment: *What* 'small portions of data'? The HTTP request will almost certainly be flushed by the library in a single send() and sent by TCP as a single packet. And setting TCP_NODELAY at your end doesn't change how the peer sends the response. Not a real question.

Comment: extra points for same with requests, a.k.a. python-requests

Comment: @user207421: Even if the request is transferred to the socket by a single `write()` or `send()`, the socket stack does not know that, and Nagle delays sending the TCP packet in order to combine it with another `write()`/`send()` call that isn't coming.

Answer (score 14):

If you need to access to such low level property on the socket used, you'll have to overload some objects.

First, you'll need to create a subclass of [HTTPHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.HTTPHandler), that in the standard library do :

```
class HTTPHandler(AbstractHTTPHandler):

    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)

    http_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_
```

As you can see, it uses a `HTTPConnection` to open connection... You'll have to override it too ;) to upgrade the `connect()` method.

Something like this should be a good start :

```
class LowLevelHTTPConnection(httplib.HTTPConnection):

    def connect(self):
        httplib.HTTPConnection.connect(self)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)


class LowLevelHTTPHandler(HTTPHandler):

    def http_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(LowLevelHTTPConnection, req)
```

urllib2 is smart enough to allow you to subclass some handler and then use it, the [urllib2.build_opener](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.build_opener) is made for this :

```
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(LowLevelHTTPHandler)) # tell urllib2 to use your HTTPHandler in replacement of the standard HTTPHandler
httpRequest = urllib2.Request("http:/www....com")
pageContent = urllib2.urlopen(httpRequest)
pageContent.readline()
```

Comment: nice solid answer! do you perhaps also know to squeeze it into urllib3 and requests?

Answer (score 9):

For requests, the classes seem to be in `request.packages.urllib3`; there are 2 classes,
HTTPConnection, and HTTPSConnection. They should be monkeypatchable in place at the module top level:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3 import connectionpool

_HTTPConnection = connectionpool.HTTPConnection
_HTTPSConnection = connectionpool.HTTPSConnection

class HTTPConnection(_HTTPConnection):
    def connect(self):
        _HTTPConnection.connect(self)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

class HTTPSConnection(_HTTPSConnection):
    def connect(self):
        _HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

connectionpool.HTTPConnection = HTTPConnection
connectionpool.HTTPSConnection = HTTPSConnection
```

Comment: awesome. I've seen this monkey-patching already for server certificate verification and sni. I hope they don't conflict.

Comment: As of the time I'm writing this, urllib3 (and hence requests) default to TCP_NODELAY.  Have a look at `requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection`, specifically `default_socket_options`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use urllib2?

Alternatively, you can use httplib2, which has the TCP_NODELAY option set.

https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/

It adds a dependency to your project, but seems less brittle than monkey patching.