# HTTP Requests using a range of IP address on python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading, httplib, httplib2

I have a VM as a server with IP address 10.91.55.2. I have another VM which acts as a client having IP address in the range 10.91.56.2......10.91.56.10. I want to write a script that will use all these IP address on the client to send HTTP request to the server (10.91.55.2). I have written a script that sends HTTP requests using the Physical IP address alone. Is there any way to send HTTP Requests from a range of IP address. 
My OS Is linux.

Comment: One server acts as master and publishes tasks (URLs) into a queue. Other servers act as clients, poll the server queue for URL, and send out actual requests.

Comment: Can yu explain further ? If possible, can you share the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but should provide you with a starting point.

You say "I have another VM which acts as a client", so I'll assume that you have a single client VM with multiple IP addresses. In this case I believe you can tell the Python [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) module to bind to a specific network interface when sending. See this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/335662/66349

This answer explicitly demonstrates its use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437870/66349

```
# from socket.h
# define SO_BINDTODEVICE 25

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, 'eth0')
```

Here is an example of calling `socket.setsockopt` in conjunction with urllib2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882197/66349

You might be able to piece those together into a functioning program.

Comment: can you help me with the script ? I'm a beginner in python and I do not know how to use the socket module.