# python socket send immediately

Tags: python, sockets

The problem with sockets is that they buffer data and send it when buffer fills or in given interval. Any way to avoid it and send something through socket with high priority, without any delay? In my case milliseconds count.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TCP_NODELAY is the option you are looking for

Sample code:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
```

For further info see

[this SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699973/how-to-set-tcp-nodelay-flag-when-loading-url-with-urllib2)

[this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tcp-ip-options-for-high-performance-data-transmission/)

[this other SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761276/when-should-i-use-tcp-nodelay-and-when-tcp-cork)

Note: on Linux systems option TCP_CORK is also available.

Experiment with both options in your application and see what happens.
Please read [this exhaustive and very informative article](http://baus.net/on-tcp_cork/) about pros and cons of both.

Comment: how to set a socket to have multiple options? e.g. NO_DELAY and REUSEADDR

Comment: just call `s.setsockopt()` for a second time (answering after a year, but whatever)