# Python TCP Socket is too slow for my multiplayer game on a real Network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, multiplayer

I have coded a drawing & guessing game simular to skribble.io and I'm using a TCP Socketserver for providing the game information to all connected players. On the client side is a thread running with a while true loop which is constently requesting for the needed information and on the server side is running a while true loop which is receiving the request and giving the right response for that. For serialization of the data I use pickle. When I'm testing my game on my local machine with a running server and some clients everything is working fine but If I'm testing it on my local network or over the internet it's starting to get very laggy on the client side and everything takes a huge amount of time to display the right server information for example a timer which is running in my game isn't updating every second and also the drawing is laggy.

Client Side:

```
def receive_data():
    global connected_clients, client, start, grid, in_game, lobby_id
    while True:
        try:
            if not in_game:
                data = network.receive()
                if isinstance(data, list):  # get connected clients
                    connected_clients = data
                    for c in connected_clients:  # get current client
                        if c.uid == client.uid:
                            client = c
                elif data == 'start':
                    start = True
                    in_game = True

            else:
                if not client.drawing:
                    res = network.get('grid')['grid']  # get grid
                    grid.update(res)

                # get round information
                topbar.word = network.get('word')['word']  # get word
                client.drawing = network.get('drawing')['drawing']
                topbar.time = network.get('time')['time']  # get round time
                topbar.round = network.get('round')['round']

                response = network.get('clients')  # get all connected clients
                connected_clients = response['clients']
                for c in connected_clients:  # get current client
                    if c.uid == client.uid:
                        client = c

                messages = network.get('chat')['chat']  # get chat
                chat.update(messages, client)
        except:
            pass
```

Network method get():

```
def get(self, data):  # returns the response for the request
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
            buff_size = 4096
            data = bytearray()
            while True:
                chunk = self.client.recv(buff_size)
                data += chunk
                if len(chunk) < buff_size:
                    break
            return pickle.loads(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Server Side:

```
def handle_player(self, connection, player):
        data = None
        send_msg = {}
        while True:
            try:
                try:
                    data = self.receive(connection)
                except:
                    pass
                if not self.in_game:  # lobby logic

                    if data == 'ready':
                        player.ready = True
                        self.broadcast(self.players_to_clients())

                    if self.all_players_ready():
                        self.broadcast('start')
                        self.game = Game(self.players)
                        for p in self.players:
                            p.set_game(self.game)
                        self.in_game = True

                elif self.in_game:  # in game logic
                    if player.game:

                        if isinstance(data, list):
                            player.game.grid.completely_update(data)
                        elif isinstance(data, dict):
                            player.game.make_player_guess(player, data['guess'])

                        if data == 'word':
                            send_msg['word'] = player.game.round.word
                        elif data == 'drawing':
                            player.drawing = player.game.round.player_drawing == player
                            if player.drawing:
                                send_msg['drawing'] = True
                            else:
                                send_msg['drawing'] = False
                        elif data == 'clients':
                            send_msg['clients'] = self.players_to_clients()
                        elif data == 'time':
                            send_msg['time'] = player.game.round.draw_time
                        elif data == 'grid':
                            send_msg['grid'] = player.game.grid.get_grid()
                        elif data == 'chat':
                            send_msg['chat'] = player.game.chat.messages
                        elif data == 'round':
                            send_msg['round'] = player.game.round_count

                        connection.send(pickle.dumps(send_msg))

                    else:
                        pass

            except socket.error:
                print(f'{player.name} disconnected.')
                player.game.player_disconnect(player)
                if player in self.players:
                    self.players.remove(player)
                if connection in self.connections:
                    self.connections.remove(connection)
                self.broadcast(self.players_to_clients())
                break
```

I got already an idea for a possible solution which is to switch from TCP to UDP and TCP but i don't know how to implement both in a way that I can send all necessary information.

PS: Sorry for any english mistakes and thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried TCP_NODELAY? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826762/python-socket-send-immediately

Comment: Have you considered that every time you call `network.get` it takes time? On the Internet, it could take 0.3 seconds. That means if you call it 7 times it could take 2.1 seconds.

Comment: @Malt Yes, I already tried that.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah I know it's taking too long to send the data and get back the right data, but thats actually the problem I have. So do you know how make this more time efficient?

Comment: Design it so the client doesn't ever need to wait for the server?

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try.

Comment: I made the server socket non-blocking now, so he is constantly sending data to the clients. This pushed the performance a little bit but the laggs still remain.